# TCP receive without stripping packet headers

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way that I could receive network packets from a TCP socket without them being stripped of the packet headers. Similar to if I had sniffed the packets while they go between the client/server TCP sockets but without doing that.

Alternatively a way to setup a network endpoint that sends all packets to my C program?

Comment: SOCK_RAW ?  libpcap ?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned this is on Windows. The winsockets raw sockets documentation says "TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets." Is there a workaround for that? Trying to avoid packet winpcap.

Comment: No idea on how to avoid the method I suggest.  Checkout the tool `nmap` see how that works on the windows version.